# Erro #1111 - mysql

Tags: mysql

```
use BDCep;

select MAX(count(endereco_completo)), bairro
from tend_endereco 
inner join tend_bairro
on tend_bairro.id_bairro = tend_endereco.id_bairro
where tend_bairro.id_cidade = 109 
GROUP by bairro ORDER by COUNT(endereco_completo) desc;
```

> #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Em síntese, eu tô com uma atividade para treinar mysql, e a pergunta é "Qual o bairro de Maceió com maior número de logradouros?", assim eu tentei usar a função max(), mas deu esse problema(erro #1111). Eu pesquisei muito sobre esse erro, mas nada que me guiasse à resposta. A pergunta de fato é, por que eu não posso usar essa função desse modo e como eu poderia responder essa atividade?

Obs: O banco tem 5 tabelas-

```
endereco_completo(
  logradouro varchar(300),
  endereco varchar(300), 
  bairro varchar(200), 
  cidade varchar(200), 
  uf varchar(2), 
  cep varchar(9)
);

tend_bairro(
  id_bairro (Primária) int(11), 
  id_cidade int(11), 
  bairro (200)
);

tend_cidade(
  id_cidade (Primária) int(11),
  id_estado int(11), 
  cidade varchar(200)
);

tend_endereco(
  cep (Primária) varchar(9),
  id_cidade int(11),
  id_bairro int(11),
  logradouro varchar(300),
  endereco varchar(300),
  endereco_completo varchar(300)
); 

tend_estado(
  id_estado (Primária) int(11)
  estado varchar(150)
  uf varchar(2)
).
```

Obs2: elas estão conectadas por fk certinho.

Answer (score 1):

Em *mysql*, podes usar o [`LIMIT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp):

```
SELECT COUNT(endereco_completo), bairro
FROM tend_endereco 
INNER JOIN tend_bairro ON tend_bairro.id_bairro = tend_endereco.id_bairro
WHERE tend_bairro.id_cidade = 109 
GROUP BY bairro
ORDER BY COUNT(endereco_completo) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```